# My While Statement is not clearing mysqli_query on second run. Is this normal?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to create an un-ordered list of weekly dates. But these dates should only populated what is applicable. In my db i have entries with dates ranging from 10/17 - 11/5.
the idea is to get the first date available then search for it and create the 1st week

> `<li>date - date</li>`

Then add a week and search for a date in that week and print the following week sequence, then add a week, etc...

Below is my code:

```
$fromDt_info = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM " . $rec_table . " WHERE `date`='".$from_dt."'" );  
echo '<ul>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fromDt_info)){
    echo $row['0'];
    $to_dt = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($from_dt . '+ 6 Days'));
    echo '<li><a href="mileage-records.php?list=past_records&from_date='.$from_dt.'&to_date='.$to_dt.'">'.date('m/d/Y',strtotime($from_dt)).' - '.date('m/d/Y',strtotime($to_dt)).'</a></li>';
    $from_dt = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($from_dt . '+ 7 Days'));
    //empty array somehow? Prints as many emtries for first date only. But prints updated dates in sequance.
}
echo '</ul>';
```

This is the result i am getting:

> 44 10/17/2014 - 10/23/2014
>
> 45 10/24/2014 - 10/30/2014
>
> 46 10/31/2014 - 11/06/2014
>
> 47 11/07/2014 - 11/13/2014
>
> 48 11/14/2014 - 11/20/2014

you can see it's printing two extra lines that i don't have entries for.
When i added the echo $row['0']; to print the `id`, then i noted it's printing all of the entries for the first date, which is five entries on that first date, but the dates printed are squential not relating to the `id` entry.

Do i need to somehow empty the array at the end of the while statement?

This is the Data in my db:

> id    date
>
> 44    2014-10-17
>
> 45    2014-10-17
>
> 46    2014-10-17
>
> 47    2014-10-17
>
> 48    2014-10-17
>
> 51    2014-10-20
>
> 52    2014-10-20
>
> 53    2014-10-20
>
> 55    2014-10-20
>
> 56    2014-10-20
>
> 57    2014-10-20
>
> 58    2014-10-21
>
> 59    2014-10-21
>
> 60    2014-10-21
>
> 61    2014-10-21
>
> 62    2014-10-21
>
> 63    2014-10-21
>
> 64    2014-10-21
>
> 65    2014-10-22
>
> 66    2014-10-22
>
> 67    2014-10-22
>
> 68    2014-10-22
>
> 69    2014-10-23
>
> 70    2014-10-23
>
> 71    2014-10-23
>
> 72    2014-10-24
>
> 73    2014-10-24
>
> 278   2014-10-27
>
> 279   2014-10-27
>
> 280   2014-10-27
>
> 281   2014-10-27
>
> 282   2014-10-27
>
> 283   2014-10-27
>
> 284   2014-10-27
>
> 285   2014-10-28
>
> 286   2014-10-28
>
> 287   2014-10-28
>
> 288   2014-10-29
>
> 289   2014-10-29
>
> 290   2014-10-29
>
> 291   2014-10-29
>
> 293   2014-10-30
>
> 294   2014-10-30
>
> 295   2014-10-30
>
> 296   2014-10-30
>
> 297   2014-10-30
>
> 298   2014-10-30
>
> 299   2014-10-31
>
> 300   2014-10-31
>
> 301   2014-10-31
>
> 302   2014-10-31
>
> 303   2014-10-31
>
> 304   2014-10-31
>
> 305   2014-11-03
>
> 306   2014-11-03
>
> 307   2014-11-03
>
> 308   2014-11-03
>
> 309   2014-11-04
>
> 310   2014-11-04
>
> 311   2014-11-04
>
> 312   2014-11-04
>
> 313   2014-11-04
>
> 314   2014-11-05
>
> 315   2014-11-05
>
> 316   2014-11-05
>
> 317   2014-11-05
>
> 318   2014-11-05
>
> 319   2014-11-05
>
> 320   2014-11-05

Comment: It's normal for `<li>` to print out like that. However, you can get rid of the `."<br>"` in `echo $from_dt."<br>";` since that will give you an extra line break. If you want to minimize the gap between `<li>` you will need CSS for it.

Comment: Thank you for that input, but this is n't related to my question. i am asking about my while statement and how it interacts with mysqli_query.

Comment: You're welcome. I had a funny feeling about that lol. I'll have to re-read your question again. I've read it a few times, and thought that's what the question was about.

Comment: @LeeHamilton - your first query is returning five rows, with IDs from 44 to 48. So your loop is running five times. As far as I can tell, the only information you're pulling from the database is the ID - the dates are being generated separately, and you're not using the one from the database at all.

Comment: Ahh, so what i am really trying to say is
While (my query is valid){make the li - /li}
Can i do this?

Comment: Isn't that what you're basically or partially doing right now with your `href`s? Just add another set of those to the ones you want to echo as a list.

Comment: no, i think right now its saying WHILE(get my query and loop it){make the li - /li}

I don't really want to get anything I want to validate information in the db.